# Netlogo: values of same breed variables won't sum. The values are created and updated from models connected to the turtles via Levelspace

Tags: netlogo

I am currently creating a Multi-level ABM using Levelspace. In the parent model I'm trying to sum the values of one variable of multiple turtles of the same breed (the number of turtles are determined by a different breeds-own variable). The variable for each turtle receives it's value from their respective child models connected via Levelspace.

Currently the parent model can receive the values from the child models. I have written a code that has a parent model turtle select particular turtles representing child models, have those selected turtles constantly update their variables totals (received from their respective child models) and display each updated total at each tick.

My problem is summing each updated child model totals into one total in the parent model that updates after each tick. Here's the code that so far:

```
ask turtle 0 [
    if breed = Epics
    [
      let closteams Teams with [AsgnEpic = "Epic 1"]
      foreach sort-on [who] closteams
      [
        the-closeteams -> ask the-closeteams [show reduce + [Value] of the-closeteams]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

I've added a variable in the foreach block and tried to sum the totals but only received 0 as an output (see code below):

```
foreach sort-on [who] closteams
      [
        the-closeteams -> ask the-closeteams [show reduce + [Value] of the-closeteams]
        let vartot sum [value] of closteams
      ]
```

Can anyone guide me on how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Rudy

```
   ----------------------------------UPDATED INFO-----------------------------------
```

The model has three levels consisting of several models connected by the Levelspace extension.

The top level is the parent model. The parent model is a Graphical User Interface model created with the extrawidget extension. Users enter information in this parent model to customize the model. This Graphical User Interface model sends all entered information to a second model (the first level child model) via Levelspace. The second model is where the user runs the model.

Here is the part of the setup procedure from the second model (the first child model). It creates Epics and teams (teams call their own child models (the second level child models) via Levelspace):

```
to setup
  ls:reset
  let n length TotEpics
  let horizontal-interval (world-width / n)
  foreach n-values n [ [i] -> i ] [ [i] ->
    create-Epics 1 [
      set label item i TotEpics
      set color item i ColorEpics
      set shape "box"
      setxy (min-pxcor - 0.5 + horizontal-interval * (0.5 + who)) 15
      set size 8
    ]
  ]
 let o length TN1
  foreach n-values o [ [i] -> i ] [ [i] ->
    create-Teams 1 [
      set label item i TN1
      set color color
      set Members item i TM1
      set AsgnEpic item i Epic1
      set Value []
      set xcor -16
      set ycor 12 + i * -7
      set size 4.5
      ls:create-interactive-models 1 "Problem_Solving.nlogo"
      set model-id last ls:models
      ls:hide model-id
    ]
  ask Teams [
    if AsgnEpic = "Epic 1" [
      create-link-with epic 0
      set xcor [xcor] of epic 0
      set ycor [ycor - 8] of epic 0
      set color blue ]
      while [any? other turtles-here] [if can-move? 2 [set heading 180 fd 5 set 
      color blue + 2]]
    if model-id = 0
      [
      ls:let name label
      ls:let mem Members
      ls:let AE AsgnEpic
    ls:ask 0 [
      set Number-of-Agents mem
      set Epic AE
      setup ]
    ]
    if model-id = 1
      [
      ls:let name label
      ls:let mem Members
      ls:let AE AsgnEpic
    ls:ask 1 [
      set Number-of-Agents mem
      set Epic AE
      setup ]
    ]
     ;this is repeated several times with the model-id number and ask number 
     ;increasing incrementally to accommodate multiple teams
  ]
reset-ticks

end
```

The setup procedure does not have a "clear-all" in it because "clear-all" wipes out all the information received from the Graphical User Interface parent model.

Below is the portion of the go procedure that runs the model and collects the input for the Teams "Value" variable from their respective child models:

```
to go
ask Teams
    [
    if model-id = 0 [ls:ask 0 [go] set Value lput [average-score] ls:of 0 Value
     ]
    if model-id = 1 [ls:ask 1 [go] set Value lput [average-score] ls:of 1 Value
     ]
    ;this is repeated several times with the model-id number increasing 
    ;incrementally to accommodate multiple teams
]
Value-of-Stories1
tick
end
```

So the "Value" variable of each team receives it's value from a separate Levelspace connected child models "average-score" global variable. I then sum the totals of each teams Value input every tick with the code below.

```
to Value-of-Stories1
ask turtle 0 [
    if breed = Epics
    [
      let closteams Teams with [AsgnEpic = "Epic 1"]
      foreach sort-on [who] closteams
      [
        the-closeteams -> ask the-closeteams [show reduce + [Value] of the- 
        closeteams]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Totaling the separate Teams "Value" totals into one number is the challenge.
There's more code then this but I believe this is the code relevant to what I'm trying to resolve.

Thanks

Rudy

Comment: When I suggested you ask a new question, I also asked for the levelspace code as that's where it appears to break. You have code for the sum, but it's not retrieving the inputs properly. If you run this code without levelspace (with some numbers in the variable Value), does it work?

Comment: Added the Levelspace code to the original question.